# Dereferencing a pointer in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, pointers

Can anyone explain me why we aren't dereferencing a pointer "now" to an NSDate instance, when we actually want to get the data from this instance, not an address.

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSLog(@"The date is %@", now);
```

The fact why i'm confused is that the previous example of `NSLog` usage in Aaron Hillegass "Objective-C Programming" book was:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSLog(@"The new date lives at %p", now);
```

This code is clear. We want address, we get it. But how do we get the actual date just by changing the specifier when we continue working with the pointer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "actual date" is a concept. The "data" is a series of bytes. They are not the same thing.

If you were using good old fashioned C-style strings and printf, you would write this:

```
char *name = "Zakatov";
printf("My name is %s", name);
```

This is because the `printf` function needs the address of the thing to work with it. You're not passing "the actual data" but the address because it is way more efficient to pass the address around. Passing something to a function means copying its value to the stack area of memory, and it's way faster to copy an address (32 or 64 bits) than to copy a whole string (several bytes, or maybe KB or MB).

So in Objective-C we deal with pointers to objects all the time, because pointers are the easiest way to refer to them. The only thing that needs to dereference the pointers (look at the bytes) is the runtime system, for example when it is translating message selectors into function addresses to execute them. Your code just treats the pointer as a pointer, and passes it around without worrying about the precise layout of the data at the other end (the bytes).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've finally understood. I'd better pay more attention to this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm glad you found it helpful. Remember to vote the useful answers up.

Comment: Thank you for the warm welcome! I wish I could vote, but I'm afraid I need to have at least 15 rep

Answer (score 8):

The variable called `now` contains a reference to a memory place.  To dereference a pointer you must do as you do in C, using `*`.

`%@` is format specifier used to print the object `description` (the string returned by its `description` method).

```
int a = 1;
int *b = &a;  // a pointer
int c = *b;   // here you dereference b
```

Answer (score 3):

In Objective-C, AFAIK you never dereference the pointer to a object (as you could do with pointers to structs). It is not unlike Java references, for example.

The question is: what data do you want to get from the `NSDate`? You should get this data through methods.

Comment: In the second code-block I get the address of `NSDate` instance called `now`. And in the first one I get the actual date. I just can't figure out why we get the date only by changing the specifier from `%p` to `%@`. (I've awaited at least an error that it's impossible to get the address in the string format)

Comment: Check out [String format specifiers](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html) more importantly the description for what `%@` and `%p` actually give you

Answer (score 2):

You can't dereference it because all Objective-C types are interfaces. In terms of fields, you do not know what's behind the pointer; in fact, your `NSDate` object probably isn't even an instance of the `NSDate` class. It just happens to implement all the methods `NSDate` exposes.

The pointer is enough to call methods, but if you can't be certain that you really deal with an `NSDate` object, you better not try to access any field directly. Therefore, if you want to get information from an object, you need to use its methods.

The `%@` format specifier, in Cocoa functions and methods, means that the `-[NSObject description]` method should be called on the pointer to know its textual representation.